# Previewing latex in cc-mode

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex, cc-mode

I'm trying to write c/c++ code with comments in LaTeX.

My .emacs file has the single line

```
(require 'org)
```

My source c/c++ file has the single line

```
\[ \int x \]
```

If I'm in python mode, fortran mode, org mode (or almost any mode) then doing org-latex-preview renders my LaTeX correctly. However, if I'm in c/c++ mode I get the error "wrong argument type: stringp, nil" and I'm just left with the raw LaTeX.

The debug backtrace is

```
looking-at(nil)
org-element-context()
org-toggle-latex-fragment(nil)
```

<sub>Note that on my home machine I'm actually doing org-toggle-latex-fragment rather than org-latex-preview because the latter does not exist. I guess that's a different mystery, but the above problem applies to both my home and work setups.</sub>

My emacs lisp knowledge is almost non-existent but it seems to be failing to find anything that it classifies as LaTeX.

Comment: this is the first time I’ve learned that I can preview LaTeX in the code comments. amazing

Comment: I probably misunderstand what you are doing: can you post a complete file (in, say, python mode) and give a complete recipe of what you are doing and what the result is?  AFAICT, previews only work if the file is in Org mode. They don't work for me if I have a comment in a python file (but no error) and they give me an error in a C file. My tentative conclusion is that any case where it "works" is accidental.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for looking into it. I've already posted everything though. The .emacs file is empty expect for "(require 'org)". My bob.py file is empty except for "\[ \int x \]". To display the LaTeX I run either org-latex-preview or org-toggle-latex-fragment. That's it.Do you have LaTeX installed? Do you have dvipng installed (I think that's important).

Comment: When I try this it works for tmp.py, but gives an error in tmp.c, along with the recommendation to report this as a bug to the org mailing list. I'm not sure it's an actual bug though, I think `org-latex-preview` is meant to work in org-mode files, and it may just be a happy accident that it works in python as well? I'm not sure, but the org mailing list would be the best place to get an authoritative answer.

Comment: My `org-preview-latex-default-process` is `imagemagick` rather than `dvipng` but I now see that it *does* work in a python mode buffer - not sure what I did earlier. I still think it's accidental, so I second @Tyler's recommendation.

Comment: Actually I know what I did: I had ``\[ \int x dx \]`` in a Pyhon comment, which is what I thought you were doing: `# \[ \int x dx \]` - after all it's not legal python, so it has to go in a comment. Try previewing that.

Comment: @NickD Your right. On my home machine adding the # breaks it. I swear that worked on my work machine. Doesn't look like this is going to work then :-(